# Prove the convergence of $b_n=\log(\frac n{n+1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $b_n=\log\left(\dfrac n{n+1}\right)$
How can I prove that: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=0$$
using an $\epsilon$-$N$ argument.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose a positive integer $N > \frac{1}{\exp(\epsilon)-1}$. Note $|b_n| = \log(1 + \frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether you have the continuity of the logarithm function available to cite.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  By continuity of $x\to\log x$ at $x=1$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|(\log x)-(\log 1)|<\varepsilon$.  So the problem then is to that there is an integer $N$ so large that whenever $n\ge N$ then $\left|\dfrac n {n+1} - 1\right|<\delta$.

So
$$
\left| \frac n {n+1} - 1 \right| = \frac 1 {n+1} < \delta \text{ if } n +1 > \frac 1 \delta.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log(\frac{n}{n+1})=\log n-\log(n+1)=\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$.